# Boost TCP Socket blocking indefinetly

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am debugging this library: https://github.com/IntelAI/he-transformer, because it is a bit too unreliable for me to use in its current state.

There seems to be a problem in the client-server communication, to be specific in the file `src/seal/he_seal_executable.cpp`. The following code sometimes blocks somewhere in the last three lines:

```
  for (const auto& pb_tensor : pb_tensors) {
    pb::TCPMessage result_msg;
    result_msg.set_type(pb::TCPMessage_Type_RESPONSE);
    *result_msg.add_he_tensors() = pb_tensor;

    // ...

    m_session->write_message(TCPMessage(std::move(result_msg)));
  }

  // Wait until message is written
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_result_mutex);
  std::condition_variable& writing_cond = m_session->is_writing_cond();
  writing_cond.wait(mlock, [this] { return !m_session->is_writing(); });
}
```

`is_writing` simply checks whether a message queue is empty. The corresponding client code (`src/seal/he_seal_client.cpp`) looks like this:

```
void HESealClient::handle_result(const pb::TCPMessage& message) {

    // ...
    close_connection();
  }
```

Where `close_connection` calls this function (in `src/tcp/tcp_client.cpp`):

```
/// \brief Closes the socket
void TCPClient::close() {
  NGRAPH_HE_LOG(1) << "Closing socket";
  m_socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
  boost::asio::post(m_io_context, [this]() { m_socket.close(); });
}
```

If I comment out `close_connection();` it seems like the server terminates reliably.

Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with boost, or even c++ in general so I haven't been making much progress on this. I think that the server is asynchronously emptying the message queue in the background:

```
void TCPSession::do_write() {

 // ...

  boost::asio::async_write(
      m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(m_write_buffer),
      [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /* length */) {
        NGRAPH_CHECK(!ec, "Server error writing message: ", ec.message());
        m_message_queue.pop_front();
        if (!m_message_queue.empty()) {
          do_write();
        } else {
          m_is_writing.notify_all();
        }
      });
}
```

And I suppose, this stops when there is no client listening to the messages. I apologize if this question is too vague but I am hoping someone with some experience in this topic can see some glaring mistake in the code that will help me make the library usable.

I tried commenting out the line `close_connection();` in `HESealClient::handle_result`, which seems to fix the problem of the server 'hanging', but that is not a solution unfortunately, since it causes the client to never terminate.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like someone must have extensive knowledge of that software library in order to have any idea what any of this does, or means. Brief code snippets are rarely sufficient enough to form a [mre], as explained in Stackoverflow's [help], without which it's unlikely anyone will be able to tell you anything useful. The "more experience in this topic" means someone who is very familiar with this library, since without a [mre] it's unlikely that a "glaring mistake" can be identified. Who's to say that the "glaring mistake" is in the shown code snippets, and not somewhere else?

Comment: Sounds like it's probably a bug in the library

Comment: if you are familiar with boost and c++ then debugging a broken library written by someone else is a difficult task. If you are not familiar with boost or c++ it is perhaps easier to find a non-broken library

Comment: @SamVarshavchik agreed that the question could just have posted the 113 lines of tcp_session.[hc]pp. Not too hard to find though.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number From the looks of it there is not going to be much competition in this particular field. The project needs to be picked up by new maintainers.

Comment: @sehe Absolutely, the reason why I am using this library is because there aren't a lot of libraries for privacy preserving ML, which is a very important topic in my opinion. I am working on this for my masters thesis, so hopefully I will eventually understand the code enough to improve it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition variable/mutex combo suggest thread-awareness. However, the interface (e.g. `write_message`) is racy in the presence of threads:

```
void TCPSession::write_message(TCPMessage&& message) {
  bool write_in_progress = is_writing();
  m_message_queue.emplace_back(std::move(message));
  if (!write_in_progress) {
    do_write();
  }
}
```

It does look like there's only a single IO thread for any given HESealExecutable, but that's different from the main thread. You might want to fix the race condition by posting to the service thread, which acts as [the implicit strand](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html):

```
void TCPSession::write_message(TCPMessage&& message) {
  post(m_socket.get_executor(),
       [this, self = shared_from_this(), msg = std::move(message)]() mutable {
         bool const write_in_progress = is_writing();
         m_message_queue.emplace_back(std::move(msg));
         if (!write_in_progress) {
           do_write();
         }
       });
}
```

In fact, the whole mutex/cv dance is probably "thread-safety cargo cult" at this point, I'll leave an in-depth review/refactor to others. At the very least `is_writing_cond()` very much seems to violate encapsulation ([Demeter Frowns Deeply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)). The same goes for the entire low-level reading interface, which can and should be made private.

### Minimal Review Fix

Including the required edits to clang-format rules to avoid spurious edits :)

```
diff --git a/.clang-format b/.clang-format
index 5650f22..d34963b 100644
--- a/.clang-format
+++ b/.clang-format
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 BasedOnStyle: Google
-DerivePointerAlignment: false
+IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
+DerivePointerAlignment: true
diff --git a/src/tcp/tcp_session.cpp b/src/tcp/tcp_session.cpp
index 7933d24..dfc5ce6 100644
--- a/src/tcp/tcp_session.cpp
+++ b/src/tcp/tcp_session.cpp
@@ -34,7 +34,17 @@ TCPSession::TCPSession(
     : m_socket(std::move(socket)),
       m_message_callback(std::bind(message_handler, std::placeholders::_1)) {}
 
-void TCPSession::do_read_header() {
+void TCPSession::start() {
+  // Here posting to the strand is probably redundant as a typical listener
+  // will immediaitely invoke `start()` on a newly constructed session
+  // instance, so by definition no other thread(s) can hold a reference to it.
+  // However in the interest of showing the principles, lets post to IO
+  // service:
+  post(m_socket.get_executor(),
+       [this, self = shared_from_this()] { do_read_header(); });
+}
+
+void TCPSession::do_read_header() {  // assumed on strand
   if (m_read_buffer.size() < header_length) {
     m_read_buffer.resize(header_length);
   }
@@ -52,7 +62,7 @@ void TCPSession::do_read_header() {
       });
 }
 
-void TCPSession::do_read_body(size_t body_length) {
+void TCPSession::do_read_body(size_t body_length) {  // assumed on strand
   m_read_buffer.resize(header_length + body_length);
 
   auto self(shared_from_this());
@@ -71,14 +81,17 @@ void TCPSession::do_read_body(size_t body_length) {
 }
 
 void TCPSession::write_message(TCPMessage&& message) {
-  bool write_in_progress = is_writing();
-  m_message_queue.emplace_back(std::move(message));
-  if (!write_in_progress) {
-    do_write();
-  }
+  post(m_socket.get_executor(),
+       [this, self = shared_from_this(), msg = std::move(message)]() mutable {
+         bool const write_in_progress = is_writing();
+         m_message_queue.emplace_back(std::move(msg));
+         if (!write_in_progress) {
+           do_write();
+         }
+       });
 }
 
-void TCPSession::do_write() {
+void TCPSession::do_write() {  // assumed on strand!
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_write_mtx);
   m_is_writing.notify_all();
   auto self(shared_from_this());
diff --git a/src/tcp/tcp_session.hpp b/src/tcp/tcp_session.hpp
index fdd3e76..221de62 100644
--- a/src/tcp/tcp_session.hpp
+++ b/src/tcp/tcp_session.hpp
@@ -38,14 +38,7 @@ class TCPSession : public std::enable_shared_from_this<TCPSession> {
              const std::function<void(const TCPMessage&)>& message_handler);
 
   /// \brief Start the session
-  void start() { do_read_header(); }
-
-  /// \brief Reads a header
-  void do_read_header();
-
-  /// \brief Reads message body of specified length
-  /// \param[in] body_length Number of bytes to read
-  void do_read_body(size_t body_length);
+  void start();
 
   /// \brief Adds a message to the message-writing queue
   /// \param[in,out] message Message to write
@@ -61,6 +54,13 @@ class TCPSession : public std::enable_shared_from_this<TCPSession> {
  private:
   void do_write();
 
+  /// \brief Reads a header
+  void do_read_header();
+
+  /// \brief Reads message body of specified length
+  /// \param[in] body_length Number of bytes to read
+  void do_read_body(size_t body_length);
+
  private:
   std::deque<TCPMessage> m_message_queue;
   TCPMessage m_read_message;
```

Comment: You're my personal hero. Although I don't really understand what's going on. How can there be a race condition if there is only one thread and it immediately blocks after calling write_message?

Comment: There are two threads, as my answer exlains.