# When do I need to dispatch to strand with Boost Beast?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-beast

I have this code from Boost Beast async chat server examples:

```
void ChatServer::StartAccept() {
    acceptor.async_accept(
        boost::asio::make_strand(acceptor.get_executor()), 
        [self = shared_from_this()] (error_code err, tcp::socket socket) {
            if (err) return self->Fail(err, "Failed to accept connection");

            std::make_shared<HttpSession>(std::move(socket), self->sslContext,  self->room)->Start();

            self->StartAccept();
        });
}
```

Now I understand that I have to make a separate strand for each connection/socket, because I'm running one io_context in multiple threads. If I don't do that, I could have threads reading/writing from the same socket which is a data race.

However in the example they still use dispatch to the executor associated with the socket, which is strand?

```
void HttpSession::Start() {
    boost::asio::dispatch(
        stream.get_executor(),
        [self = shared_from_this()]() {
            self->DoSslHandshake();
        });
}
```

Why do I have to use dispatch here? Isn't every socket already associated with its own strand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not required, but that's only coincidental. The code expresses intent.

> Re: > Why do I have to use dispatch here? Isn't every socket already associated with its own strand?
>
> *That's irrelevant. The IO object's executor will only serve as the default for unbound completion tokens. However, what the `dispatch` is guarding is *initiation* not (intermediate) handler invocation.*

In fact, many of the library examples have an explanatory comment:

```
// Start the asynchronous operation
void
run()
{
    // We need to be executing within a strand to perform async operations
    // on the I/O objects in this session. Although not strictly necessary
    // for single-threaded contexts, this example code is written to be
    // thread-safe by default.
    net::dispatch(
        stream_.get_executor(),
        beast::bind_front_handler(
            &session::on_run,
            shared_from_this()));
}
```

I've elaborated on this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75592969/85371) more relevant to your context:

```
void TCPSession::start() {
  // Here posting to the strand is probably redundant as a typical listener
  // will immediaitely invoke `start()` on a newly constructed session
  // instance, so by definition no other thread(s) can hold a reference to it.
  // However in the interest of showing the principles, lets post to IO
  // service:
  post(m_socket.get_executor(),
       [this, self = shared_from_this()] { do_read_header(); });
}
```

Or, [similary, but way more brief](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71745354/85371):

```
void Connection::start() { // always assumed on the strand (since connection
                            // just constructed)
     do_read();
 }
```